# ViewPager's item is automatically destroyed when navigating back or on configuration changes

Tags: android, kotlin-flow, android-viewpager2

My application contains ViewPager with Fragments, like this:
`MainActivity`(`TitleHomeFragment`(`ViewPager`(`TitlePageItemFragment`))), which means:

`Activity` contains `Fragment` contains `ViewPager` contains `Fragments`

My issue is when configuration changes or when I navigate back `TitleHomeFragment`, the current fragment displayed in ViewPager is destroyed. What I mean here is that it is really destroyed. Here is my log:

```
TitleHomeFragment       vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onCreateView()
TitleHomeFragment       vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         D  launching view lifecycle
TitleHomeFragment       vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onViewCreated()
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onCreateView()
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onViewCreated()
---HERE PROBLEM OCCURS---
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onDestroyView() => **why is it destroying my fragment?**
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onDestroy()
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onDetach()
TitleHomeFragment       vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onStart()
TitleHomeFragment       vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         D  genre view state = Success(data=[GenreViewState(genre=Action, selected=true), GenreViewState(genre=Adult, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Adventure, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Animation, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Biography, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Comedy, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Crime, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Documentary, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Drama, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Family, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Fantasy, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Film-Noir, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Game-Show, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=History, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Horror, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Music, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Musical, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Mystery, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=News, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Reality-TV, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Romance, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Sci-Fi, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Short, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Sport, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Talk-Show, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Thriller, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=War, selected=false), GenreViewState(genre=Western, selected=false)])
TitleHomeFragment       vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onResume()
TitlePageI...enre: null vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onAttach()
TitlePageI...enre: null vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onCreate()
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onCreateView()
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onViewCreated()
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onStart()
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         D  androidx.paging.PagingData@6f3e2c
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         D  current load state: CombinedLoadStates(refresh=Loading(endOfPaginationReached=false), prepend=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false), append=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false), source=LoadStates(refresh=Loading(endOfPaginationReached=false), prepend=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false), append=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false)), mediator=null)
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         I  onResume()
TitlePageI...re: Action vn.com.phucars.awesomemovies         D  current load state: CombinedLoadStates(refresh=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false), prepend=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=true), append=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false), source=LoadStates(refresh=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false), prepend=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=true), append=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false)), mediator=null)
```

The mysterious part is that why the child fragment is being restart (`onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` were called), it is then immediately destroyed completely (the associated view model's `onCleared` is called), hence all the api needed for the fragment was once again called.

**EDIT:** I don't know this is related. But here I am collect a flow with repeatOnLifecycle

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            Log.d(getClassTag(), "launching view lifecycle")
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.genreViewStateFlow.collect { it -> 
                // UPDATE VIEW 
            }
}
```

I change to `Lifecycle.State.CREATED` and everything was fine. As my understanding, this thing is not related to the problem above. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What's your ViewPager's adapter offset?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini there is none, only one page display at a time

Comment: The offset is set in the ViewPager Adapter. It's to indicate how many fragments to pre-create/keep alive when scrolling (so the next one is ready before the user scrolls into it). It could be that yours is immediately destroying everything.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I don't think it's the problem. As I mentioned above, I can eliminate the unexpected behavior by changing Lifecycle state.

Comment: Also, I changed the page offset to any values, issue still happens